# N-queens in Scala

Tags: scala, n-queens

```
  def queens(n: Int): List[List[(Int, Int)]] = {
    def placeQueens(k: Int): List[List[(Int, Int)]] =
      if (k == 0)
        List(List())
      else
        for {
          queens <- placeQueens(k - 1)
          column <- 1 to n
          queen = (k, column)
          if isSafe(queen, queens)
        } yield queen :: queens
    placeQueens(n)
  }
```

I don't understand how this code works, even tough I debugged in Eclipse. Can you explain step by step this code? By the way, code works correctly. I also understand the n-queens algorithm but I don't understand the mechanism of this code.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down.

```
def queens(n: Int): List[List[(Int, Int)]] = {
  def placeQueens(k: Int): List[List[(Int, Int)]] =
    if (k == 0)
      List(List())
    else
      for {
        queens <- placeQueens(k - 1)
        column <- 1 to n
        queen = (k, column)
        if isSafe(queen, queens)
      } yield queen :: queens
  placeQueens(n)
}
```

We define a function `queens(n: Int)` which returns every possible placement of n queens on an n*n chessboard. The functions `queens` itself is very simple; it just delegates to an inner function, called `placeQueens`.

`placeQueens` has a base case listed first: if we are operating on a 0*0 chessboard and placing 0 queens, there is exactly one (very trivial) way to do it. Now, the meat of this function is in the for-loop.

```
for {
  queens <- placeQueens(k - 1)
  column <- 1 to n
  queen = (k, column)
  if isSafe(queen, queens)
} yield queen :: queens
```

Parts of this can be read like a "traditional" for-loop, but some of it is not so straightforward. Scala's for-loop is based on Haskell's do-loop syntax, which probably explains some of your confusion. The way to read this is:

```
// We're starting a for-loop
for {
  // Call placeQueens recursively. placeQueens returns a list of
  // all possible results, so iterate over them.
  queens <- placeQueens(k - 1)
  // Iterate over each column that the kth queen could go in.
  column <- 1 to n
  // Assign the queen to that position.
  queen = (k, column)
  // If the position is safe, keep going. More precisely, if the position
  // is NOT safe, stop.
  if isSafe(queen, queens)
// Put our new queen assignment at the beginning of the recursively computed list.
} yield queen :: queens
```

These loops take some getting used to. It can be educational to desugar the loop (which is what the compiler does anyway) by hand to see what it means. You can find the translation rules [on the Scala website](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html).

Comment: `if (k == 0)
      List(List())
    else
      for {
        queens <- placeQueens(k - 1)`

Here is the point: In the part of code as left, when I am debugging, k iterates to 4,3,2,1,0, then if statement is true. After that, k equals to 1. How is it possible?

Comment: @coder, When `k==0` then an empty `List()` is returned _from this iteration_. Returned to where? Returned to the previous iteration where `k==1`. If you continue to step through the code you should see the current iteration return from the `yield`, in the `else` block, to the _previous iteration_ where `k==2`, and so on.

Comment: "Returned to the previous iteration where `k==1` " this is really odd and confusing. Is there a clearer example including for loop and recursion in Scala.